# How to get distribution of a column in R

Tags: r, stack-overflow

Im working on stackoverflow data dump .csv file and I need to to find the distribution of scores for questions.

I opened the file in R and extracted the two columns that I need which are the PostTypeID and Score.

example :

[image: Example]

I need to find :

3 rows in the score column that has the score 11.

2 rows in the score column that has the score 3.
.... etc

The thing is the data is too large, it has 3 million rows
and I don't know how to get the distribution.

Note I'm a beginner in R, so I need the simplest way to do that.

Comment: You mention *"filter"* and *"get the distribution"*, the two are not the same. Please read about how to ask good questions (refs https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), and then edit your question. Some pointers: consumable data (e.g., `dput`) and desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the `table` function.

If `d` is your data structure, then you want

`table(d$Score)`

Comment: how I can I plot that ?

Comment: Do you mean `hist(x$Score)`?

Comment: I want to plot the result I got from" table(d$Score)"

Answer (score 1):

x=data[, score==3] to get rows with score 3

Comment: There are millions of scores, 3 was an example

Comment: do you mean `data[data$score==3,]`? you are filtering on columns (not rows and `score` is likely not defined by itself.

Comment: All the rows will be returned but if you want to filter further the use data[, score==3|posttypeid=2 ] or use head() tail() functions to specify number of rows you want in result.

Comment: I guess fetching row is more beneficial so i wrote that for rows.